# How to disable XDebug

Tags: php, xdebug, apc

I think that my server became slow since I installed XDebug.
So, in order to test my hypothesis I want to disable XDebug completely.
I've been searching for tutorials on how to do this but I can't find such information.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Find your `php.ini` and look for XDebug.

Set xdebug autostart to false

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=0  
xdebug.remote_enable=0
```

Disable your profiler

```
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

Note that there can be a [performance loss even with xdebug disabled but loaded](https://web.archive.org/web/20170404001727/http://www.frankmayer.me:80/blog/item/12-xdebug-disabling-vs-not-loading-it-at-all). To disable loading of the extension itself, you need to comment it in your php.ini. Find an entry looking like this:

```
zend_extension = "/path/to/php_xdebug.dll"
```

and put a `;` to comment it, e.g. `;zend_extension = …`.

Check out this post [XDebug, how to disable remote debugging for single .php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570680/xdebug-how-to-disable-remote-debugging-for-single-php-file)

Comment: Thanks! I found that my problem was APC, my memory was low apparently. You are right, xdebug is part of PHP, not a module of Apache. Now everything is running fine.

Comment: @Uday and what if I can't find any of this in my php.ini. I've checked everywhere inside /etc/php including with grep search.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev Check phpinfo() to see if xdebug is actually enabled. if it is, check if you have any additional ini files attached to php.ini file. Additionally make sure you are editing correct ini file. it is possible to have these files at multiple locations.

Comment: @UdaySawant I was able to disable it after commenting the line `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so` from `/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini`. However neither in `/usr/lib/php5` nor in `/etc` the lines specified in the answer are available.

Comment: Actually, it's better to not load the extension at all, and only load it, if needed. XDebug actually slows things down a lot, even if disabled.
One might not feel performance has degraded that much, when debugging/profiling some scripts that create a web page, but with daemon scripts, it shows a lot. I just wrote a blog post on why not loading it at all, is better, here: http://bit.ly/14SaWpp

Comment: @thesilentman I read your blog post. Need to test this on my own. Just for a cross check, EasyPHP uses two separate files one for web pages (apache) and one for console apps. Hope you have edited correct ini file.

Comment: @UdaySawant Hmm... In my installation (dev 13.1) there's only one ini. The one in runningversion (for the active version) folder. However every time I changed something, I also did a php -i to check. BTW, the testfiles are in this gist:https://gist.github.com/frankmayer/6268139
I've updated the Blog post accordingly

Comment: Thats not the full solution for me... see here which Flag was missing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30189745/1256697

Comment: That no longer is the correct answer. See mine down below.

Answer (score 103):

An easy solution working on Linux distributions similar to Ubuntu

```
sudo php5dismod xdebug
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: That command is for ubuntu not centOS. Should provide that explanation because you are not the only person use the same linux distro.

Comment: You should really note that this only works on certain OSes, in this case it appears to be Ubuntu. It definitely doesn't work on my Mac either way.

Comment: this is for apache2 and not for CLI. These might have different php.ini files

Comment: Depending of your PHP version, you should enter `$ sudo phpdismod xdebug`

Comment: This answer only applies to PHP when it's being used with Apache's mod-php.

Answer (score 48):

In **Linux Ubuntu**(*maybe also another - it's not tested*) distribution with **PHP 5** on board, you can use:

```
sudo php5dismod xdebug
```

And with **PHP 7**

```
sudo phpdismod xdebug
```

And after that, please restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: PHP 7 removed xdebug from the ini file, I believe. So this answer helped me.

Comment: Worked for PHP7. Commenting the xdebug settings out in the php.ini didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work. WARNING: Module xdebug ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

Comment: php -v; phpdismod -v 7.4 xdebug; Change 7.4 to php version according to echo first command.

Answer (score 27):

Also, you can add `xdebug_disable()` to your code. Try:

`if(function_exists('xdebug_disable')) { xdebug_disable(); }`

Comment: This only disables displaying stacktraces, it does not actually disable xdebug (terribly named function, I know)

Comment: This is an awesome way to deal with a lot of situations. Thanks for this even if it doesn't really meat OP's needs.

Comment: @Jake, I'm not sure the OP was looking for a butcher.

Comment: @thephpdev Took me a second... but I got it... can't fix that now.

Comment: @Jake hehe. Was only kidding anyway. 

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft why is it a terribly named function?

Comment: @BinarWeb because people could think this function disables the whole xdebug and improves performance, but it's not

Answer (score 15):

I renamed the config file and restarted server:

```
$ mv /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini.bak

$ sudo service php7.0-fpm restart && sudo service nginx restart
```

It did work for me.

Comment: This worked for me, except in /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d instead of /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d

Comment: This will also work on php 7.2,9 on mac osx or on centos vagrant. Just rename to xdebug.ini to xdebug.ini.old or something else

Comment: This is it chief

Comment: For the non-fpm PHP:
sudo mv /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini.bak

Answer (score 11):

Comment extension in php.ini and restart Apache. Here is a simple script (you can assign shortcut to it)

xdebug-toggle.php

```
define('PATH_TO_PHP_INI', 'c:/xampp/php/php.ini');
define('PATH_TO_HTTPD', 'c:/xampp/apache/bin/httpd.exe');
define('REXP_EXTENSION', '(zend_extension\s*=.*?php_xdebug)');

$s = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_PHP_INI);
$replaced = preg_replace('/;' . REXP_EXTENSION . '/', '$1', $s);
$isOn = $replaced != $s;
if (!$isOn) {
    $replaced = preg_replace('/' . REXP_EXTENSION . '/', ';$1', $s);
}
echo 'xdebug is ' . ($isOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF') . " now. Restarting apache...\n\n";
file_put_contents(PATH_TO_PHP_INI, $replaced);

passthru(PATH_TO_HTTPD . ' -k restart');
```

Comment: In order to really disable XDebug completely, this one is the correct answer, see my comment in @UdaySawant's answer.

Answer (score 10):

Since xdebug 3 came out the settings in `pnp.ini` have slightly changed.
Setting:

```
xdebug.mode=off
```

Will disable all [processing](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) According to the docs:

> Nothing is enabled. Xdebug does no work besides checking whether
> functionality is enabled. Use this setting if you want close to 0
> overhead.

Answer (score 9):

in xubuntu I totally disabled xdebug for the CLI with this...

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/*xdebug*
```

Comment: note: this really helped me out for composer updates. needed to disable xdebug for performance issues.

Comment: this works for laravel homestead, too. to disable xdebug in homestead / laravel simply comment out the section in the file `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

Comment: Worth mentioning if you run php script from terminal that runs another php script from terminal via `passthru` function with xdebug enabled, xdebug might hang and stop the execution.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was for, this appears to be the only way to disable xdebug for the CLI and not other environments. Although I'd use `unlink` over `rm` if it's available.

Comment: I wouldn't rm/unlink the ini, instead do as ulkas suggested, `sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` and comment it out.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows (WAMP) in CLI ini file:

`X:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.xx\php.ini`

comment line

```
; XDEBUG Extension

;zend_extension = "X:/wamp/bin/php/php5.x.xx/zend_ext/php_xdebug-xxxxxx.dll"
```

Apache will process `xdebug`, and composer will not.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `php-fpm` the following should be sufficient:

```
sudo phpdismod xdebug
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Notice, that you will need to tweak this depending on your php version. For instance running php 7.0 you would do:

```
sudo phpdismod xdebug
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Since, you are running php-fpm there should be no need to restart the actual webserver. In any case if you don't use fpm then you could simply restart your webserver using any of the below commands:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Greate!! sudo phpdismod xdebug
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart this solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

## Ubuntu 16.04 remove xdebug from PHP.

#### Find your php.ini file and make sure xdebug is there:

```
grep -r "xdebug" /etc/php/
```

This might come up with different versions, if so run `php -v` to find your version.

#### Edit the php.ini file, like:

```
sudo vi /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

#### Comment the line:

```
//zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

#### Save the file

Comment: Yes, you definitely need the first command to find out all the (wrong) xdebug configurations you did. Thanks!

Comment: Just learned something new with this grep command, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by PHPStorm right click on a file -> debug -> ...

```
www-data@3bd1617787db:~/symfony$ 
php 
-dxdebug.remote_enable=0 
-dxdebug.remote_autostart=0 
-dxdebug.default_enable=0 
-dxdebug.profiler_enable=0 
test.php
```

the important stuff is `-dxdebug.remote_enable=0 -dxdebug.default_enable=0`

Comment: All the other solutions about faffing with filesystem and then this. :raised_hands: True legend! This will even work in a `docker exec` and `docker run`.

Comment: for xdebug 3, use `xdebug.mode=off` or, in this case `-dxdebug.mode=off`

Answer (score 7):

You can disable Xdebug on PHP CLI on runtime using the `-d` flag:

`php -d xdebug.mode=off -i | grep xdebug.mode`

Result: `xdebug.mode => off => off`

Example, running unit tests with Xdebug disabled, so it's faster:

`php -d xdebug.mode=off ./vendor/bin/phpunit`

You can also create an alias for it to make it easier to use.

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

1: Add following code in the initialization Script:

```
 if (function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
           xdebug_disable();
         }
```

2: Add following flag to php.ini

```
 xdebug.remote_autostart=0
 xdebug.remote_enable=0
```

1st option is recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Find your PHP.ini and look for XDebug.

normally in Ubuntu its path is

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Make following changes (Better to just comment them by adding ; at the beginning )

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

then restart your server
again for Ubuntu

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

**Disable xdebug**

For PHP 7: `sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

For PHP 5: `sudo nano /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

Then comment out everything and save.

---

**UPDATE -- Disable for CLI only**

As per @igoemon's comment, this is a better method:

PHP 7.0 (NGINX)

```
sudo mv /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini.old
sudo service nginx restart
```

Note:  Update the path to your version of PHP.

Comment: Is is not a solution, because /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini is just a symlink and if you edit it, you edit the original file which is common for cli and non-cli.
I think the right solution is simple delete the symlink.

Comment: Updated answer ^.

Answer (score 5):

I created this bash script for toggling xdebug. I think it should work at least on Ubuntu / Debian. This is for PHP7+. For PHP5 use php5dismod / php5enmod.

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Toggles xdebug
#

if [ ! -z $(php -m | grep "xdebug") ] ; then
    phpdismod xdebug
    echo "xdebug is now disabled"
else
    phpenmod xdebug
    echo "xdebug is now enabled"
fi

# exit success
exit 0
```

Comment: Very helpful script. You could mention that a service restart is required for the changes to take effect, which isn't immediately obvious (at least, it was required for my system).

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue. Sometimes, you wont find xdebug.so in php.ini. In which case, execute `phpinfo()` in a php file and check for `Additional .ini files parsed`. Here you'll see more ini files. One of these will be xdebug's ini file. Just remove (or rename) this file, restart apache, and this extension will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I had following Problem: 
Even if I set

```
xdebug.remote_enable=0
```

Xdebug-Error-Message-Decoration was shown.

My solution:

```
xdebug.default_enable=0
```

Only if I use this Flag, Xdebug was disabled.

Answer (score 4):

(This is for CentOS)

Rename the config file and restart apache.

```
sudo mv /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini /etc/php.d/xdebug.ini.old
sudo service httpd restart
```

Do the reverse to re-enable.

Answer (score 3):

For WAMP, click left click on the Wamp icon in the taskbar tray. Hover over PHP and then click on php.ini and open it in your texteditor.

Now, search for the phrase 'zend_extension' and add ; (semicolon) in front it.

Restart the WAMP and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Disable xdebug only for certain PHP version or sapi.
On this case PHP 7.2 fpm

```sh
sudo phpdismod -v 7.2 -s fpm xdebug
sudo service php7.2-fpm nginx restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MAMP Pro on Mac OS X it's done via the MAMP client by unchecking *Activate Xdebug* under the *PHP* tab:

[image: Disabling Xdebug in MAMP Pro]

Answer (score 2):

So, yeah, all what you need, just comment line in INI file like `zend_extension=xdebug.so` or similar.

Comments can be made by adding semicolon.

But, such kind of answer already added, and I'd like to share ready solution to switch Xdebug status.

I've made quick switcher for Xdebug. Maybe it would be useful for someone.

[Xdebug Switcher](https://github.com/rikby/xdebug-switcher#xdebug-switcher)

Answer (score 2):

Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.2.4  myHomeBrew stack

At end of php.ini I use the following to manage Xdebug for use with PhpStorm

```
; jch ~ Sweet analizer at https://xdebug.org/wizard.php for matching xdebug to php version.
; jch ~ When upgrading php versions check if newer xdebug.dll is needed in ext directory.
; jch Renamed... zend_extension = E:\x64Stack\PHP\php7.2.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll

zend_extension = E:\x64Stack\PHP\php7.2.4\ext\php_xdebug.dll

; jch !!!! Added the following for Xdebug with PhpStorm

[Xdebug]
; zend_extension=<full_path_to_xdebug_extension>
; xdebug.remote_host=<the host where PhpStorm is running (e.g. localhost)>
; xdebug.remote_port=<the port to which Xdebug tries to connect on the host where PhpStorm is running (default 9000)>

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="E:\x64Stack\Xdebug_profiler_output"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1

; jch ~~~~~~~~~To turn Xdebug off(disable) uncomment the following 3 lines restart Apache~~~~~~~~~ 
;xdebug.remote_autostart=0  
;xdebug.remote_enable=0
;xdebug.profiler_enable=0

; !!! Might get a little more speed by also commenting out this line above... 
;;; zend_extension = E:\x64Stack\PHP\php7.2.4\ext\php_xdebug.dll
; so that Xdebug is both disabled AND not loaded
```

Comment: don't forget to restart apache to load the php changes (:

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in disabling it in codeship, run this script before running tests:

```
rm -f /home/rof/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

I was receiving this error:

```
Use of undefined constant XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED - assumed 'XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

which is now gone!

Answer (score 0):

In CLI:

```
sudo phpdismod xdebug
```

disable xdebug

```
sudo phpenmod xdebug
```

enable xdebug

And restart the server

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to make a php utility script that won't be affected by any xdebug settings or even the installed xdebug version (expecially when dealing with legacy code).

I wanted to ALWAYS run with xdebug disabled upon Linux shell sessions.
Therefore, my approach was to wrap the php script around some bash code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SCRIPT=$(cat << 'EOM'
<?php
 echo "This could be some small multiline php code";
EOM
)

echo "$SCRIPT" | php -d xdebug.mode=off

exit $?
```

The whole idea is to somehow store the code into a variable and use pipe to execute it with xdebug completely disabled. This is a usefull approach if:

- Script needs to run via command line (not via apache or fpm)
- Is a utility script that run/aids the core task (development of main app)

A exaple where this approach can be used is in:
https://github.com/pc-magas/docker_php_dev/blob/master/utils/get_xdebug_ip

This script I detect the ip where xdebug listens to. For that I wanted to use some php code in order to avoid installing extra dependencies. Also I wanted the code to run without being affected via xdebug.

Therefore, using a self-contained solution using bash seemed a good approach 2 me.