# Composer not working in Windows 8.1

Tags: composer-php

I'm having a composer problem, which looks like it's caused by updating to Windows 8.1.

Everytime I try to `composer update` or `composer install` I get the following error:

```
[ErrorException]
zlib_decode(): data error
```

When I try to `composer diagnose` I get this response:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: FAIL

The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
Disabling it when using Composer is recommended, but should not cause issues beyond slowness.
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

I'm not sure why `Checking platform settings` has `FAIL`. Where does this look for?

I never had this before, so I someone else experiencing problems as well on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

Checking platform settings fails because the xdebug extension is loaded. But this should not cause any issues beyond slowness. If you feel your composer to be slow and you don't use xdebug you can deactivate it (See here how to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754934/3219613).
This has nothing to do with your first error.

Please check if the zlib_decode extension is active with

```
php -m
```

Or for more debug messages try

```
composer -vvv update
```