# PHP/Symfony2 - print_r on Object

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have some weird things going on and I was wondering whether they are PHP or Symfony related.  Basically, from my form, an ajax request is made and the form data posted to my controller.

Now I need to do some work with the entity that has just been persisted to the database, so to get this to where it needs to go, I have an EventListener and I do

```
protected  $alertEntity;

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
        $this->alertEntity = $entity;
    }
}

public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($this->alertEntity);
}
```

So I get the entity in postPersist, and then pass it to where it needs to go in the postFlush.

This is all fine, no problems here.  The weird part is this

```
public function addFlightsAction($alert){
    print_r($alert);
}
```

If I have the above in a print_r, it goes on forever until it eventually gives the error allocation size overflow.

If I do the above in a var_dump, it prints out the alert for me, but its in an unreadable format e.g. (short extract)

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>object</b>(<i>Ontro\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert</i>)[<i>284</i>]
  <i>private</i> 'id' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>39</font>
  <i>private</i> 'searchCommand' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'A20APRLONLAX'</font> <i>(length=12)</i>
  <i>private</i> 'isConnecting' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'no'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>
  <i>private</i> 'lastUpdated' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>object</b>(<i>DateTime</i>)[<i>288</i>]
      <i>public</i> 'date' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2015-02-19 10:54:54'</font> <i>(length=19)</i>
      <i>public</i> 'timezone_type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>3</font>
      <i>public</i> 'timezone' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Europe/London'</font> <i>(length=13)</i>
  <i>private</i> 'isDeleted' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>0</font>
  <i>private</i> 'alertStatus' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Active'</font> <i>(length=6)</i>
  <i>private</i> 'bookingClass' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>object</b>(<i>Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection</i>)[<i>372</i>]
      <i>private</i> 'snapshot' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>
```

So why would it be doing this?  Is there any way I can print it out nicely so I can see it?  I dont mind the above output as long as it got rid of all the html tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got xdebug install which formats `var_dump` for you. Either disable it following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug) but that'll still give you the same issue as `print_r` with the allocation error.

If you want keep xdebug (which I imagine you do, and should), you have two options, either disable `xdebug.overload_var_dump` ([docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/display)) in your php.ini or you can use  `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($alert)` instead.

In Symfony 2.6 they have introduced a new feature, [VarDumper](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component) which is a pretty powerful debugging tool built right in. You can check out the documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html

Comment: Also, try the VarDumper component and the dump() function it provides: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html

Comment: Feel free to include it in your answer. This way it would be easier to find.