# PhpUnit test very long

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm doing some functional testing with PHPUnit in Symfony2 .

I use PHPUnit version 4.4.1 ,tests were created with the controller generation (doctrine:generate:crud)

So , I only tests the CRUD on an User, and it takes me more than 30 seconds (This varies between 30 and 40s ) . Is this comes from the code? Tests themselves ? The fact that I worked on a remote server?

Here is the test class :

```
 class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
/**
 * Test CRUD functions (Create, read, update, delete)
 */
public function testCompleteScenario()
{
    // Create a new client to browse the application
    $client = static::createClient();

    // Create a new entry in the database
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/user/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET /user/");
    $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Create a new entry')->link());

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
        's_dosfabbundle_user[login]'  => 'test.test',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[trigram]'  => 'tet',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[email]'  => 'test@test.com',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[productionUnits]'  => '11',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[roles]'  => '55',
    ));

    $client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // Check data in the show view
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('td:contains("test.test")')->count(), 'Missing element td:contains("test.test")');

    // Edit the entity
    $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Edit')->link());

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Update')->form(array(
         's_dosfabbundle_user[login]'  => 'test.testUpdate',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[trigram]'  => 'tetU',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[email]'  => 'test_update@test.com',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[productionUnits]'  => '11',
        's_dosfabbundle_user[roles]'  => '57',
    ));

    $client->submit($form);
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // Check the element contains an attribute with value equals "Foo"
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('[value="tetU"]')->count(), 'Missing element [value="tetU"]');

    // Delete the entity
    $client->submit($crawler->selectButton('Delete')->form());
    $crawler = $client->followRedirect();

    // Check the entity has been delete on the list
    $this->assertNotRegExp('/tetU/', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
}

 }
```

Comment: can you investigate in which point spent much time? trivially simply put a die after some point and see what appen. BTW from the logs `app/log/test.log` see something strange?

Comment: If I look test.log nothing spent much time than another. I don't know if you want to see it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, as more info is needed, but I had the same issue. If you've got xdebug enabled, you could try disabling it, see [disabling xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug). This is of course only relevant if you're not using it for things like code coverage (which always takes quite a while).