# Disabling XDebug on Primary Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puppet, xdebug

Is there any simple/correct way to disable Xdebug in a [Primary Vagrant](https://github.com/ChrisWiegman/Primary-Vagrant) box?

I tried setting the [xdebug PHP.ini vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug) in the /manifests/custom/php.pp puppet file, with no luck. Also commenting the xdebug lines in /manifests/init.pp with no luck either.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find: 'xdebug.ini'

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
/etc/php/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

then comment with ';'

```
;zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

then restart your nginx server

```
sudo service nginx restart
```