# var_dump has unreadable output

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have a method to dump a `var_dump` output to a file, as such:

```
function dumpToFile($object) {
    $file = "c:/tmp/php.log";
    ob_start();
    var_dump($object);
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    $fh = fopen($file, "a+");
    fwrite($fh, $output."\r\n");

}
```

Out of nowhere, the output of this is always starting with a tag like this and has some characters that are HTML encoded, like `&quot`

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump'> dump content... </pre>
```

I don't remember changing the PHP.ini file, any ideas ? I'm using `php-cgi.exe` under Windows.

`var_dump` itself outputs the garbled data, so it's not my method as far as I can see.

Comment: As you may guess from the class name in `pre` - it's `xdebug` that does that.

Comment: Right. I just commented out all the keys in `[XDebug]` config section in PHP.ini and that works. No idea how suddenly this was turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your xdebug has been enabled. See below post on how to disable:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754934