# application(or apache) is not getting loaded after some time of inactivity

Tags: php, apache

I am having a PHP web  based application which is running on Apache 2.2. 
The issue is, if I put my application in to an idle state for some time the application is not responding after that. The idle time is varying for different time. Some time it get unresponsive in 15 mins, some time 30 min or 1 hour also like that. I think my Apache is not able to make the connection here after some time of inactivity. At the same time if I am trying to access the application from different client(system) it is working fine.

I am using persistent connection with DB but the sessions are under control DB side. Somebody please help me on this.

Comment: You might want to try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) its a sub domain specialized in hosting and servers and stuff

Comment: Apache is a widely used web-server which is trusted by thousands (or millions) of people to have a maximum uptime and to not mysteriously stop working after 15 mins. This indicates that the problem is not apache but with your code, which you would need to provide to have any hopes of receiving help.

Comment: i think the below link also explain the similar problem, but the solutions given there is not giving me the desired result. Link : https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4543&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

Comment: [Disabling xdebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug) worked for me.