# var_dump() and print_r() output different values

Tags: php, http, http-headers, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I run this code:

```
<?php
     $test = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     var_dump($test);
     print_r($test);
     die();
```

I get this output:
[image]

I run this code:

```
<?php
     $test = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     print_r($test);
     var_dump($test);
     die();
```

I get this output:
[image]

Why can't `print_r()` and `var_dump()` agree on the value of $test in case 1?

For context on how I arrived here. I am running a laravel/homestead vm box, and I'm using Browsersync. Browsersync creates a proxy (`localhost:3000`) that I connect to, which points to the laravel/homestead vm (`192.168.10.10`). The proxy changes the value of the `Host` header when the request passes through it.

Comment: Also strange that `localhost:3000` is not length 13.

Comment: @AbraCadaver good catch.

Comment: This is somewhat impossible I dare say. `var_dump` also doesn't typically output the file and line number. Is your `var_dump` special somehow?

Comment: from what i read, since PHP 5.6.0, if an object implements the method `__debugInfo()`, this will be used to format / modify what will be displayed by `var_dump`. Maybe that can explain what is happening there?

Comment: You guys were right. Disabling xdebug fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Xdebug bug.

Solution: [disable xdebug.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754934/2449639)

Output with xdebug disabled:

[image]