# Disable xdebug during scrutinizer inspections

Tags: php, xdebug, scrutinizer

We're not using code coverage so there's no need for xdebug to be enabled.

Leaving it enabled but unused is adding significant overhead to our test runtime.

I understand the generic steps of how to disable xdebug but I'm looking for answers specifically with doing so whilst using scrutinizer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable XDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754826/how-to-disable-xdebug)

Comment: I'm looking for answers specific to the scrutinizer platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by editing my project's .scrutinizer.yml to include:

```
build:
    dependencies:
        before:
            - "find /home/scrutinizer/.phpenv/versions -name 'php.ini' -exec sed -i 's/^zend_extension_ts/;zend_extension_ts/' {} \\;"
```