# Php jit configuration not working properly

Tags: php, ubuntu, jit, ubuntu-20.04

i have confuse with php8 jit feature
my conf:

- zend_extension=opcache
- opcache.enable=1
- opcache.enable_cli=1
- opcache.jit=tracing
- opcache.jit_buffer_size=256M

but in dump from opcache_get_status() i have something like this:

```
[jit] => Array
        (
            [enabled] => 
            [on] => 
            [kind] => 5
            [opt_level] => 4
            [opt_flags] => 6
            [buffer_size] => 0
            [buffer_free] => 0
        )
```

dump from function opcache get configuration

```
[directives] => Array
        (
            [opcache.enable] => 1
            [opcache.enable_cli] => 1
            [opcache.use_cwd] => 1
            [opcache.validate_timestamps] => 1
            [opcache.validate_permission] => 
            [opcache.validate_root] => 
            [opcache.dups_fix] => 
            [opcache.revalidate_path] => 
            [opcache.log_verbosity_level] => 1
            [opcache.memory_consumption] => 134217728
            [opcache.interned_strings_buffer] => 8
            [opcache.max_accelerated_files] => 10000
            [opcache.max_wasted_percentage] => 0.05
            [opcache.consistency_checks] => 0
            [opcache.force_restart_timeout] => 180
            [opcache.revalidate_freq] => 2
            [opcache.preferred_memory_model] => 
            [opcache.blacklist_filename] => 
            [opcache.max_file_size] => 0
            [opcache.error_log] => 
            [opcache.protect_memory] => 
            [opcache.save_comments] => 1
            [opcache.record_warnings] => 
            [opcache.enable_file_override] => 
            [opcache.optimization_level] => 2147401727
            [opcache.lockfile_path] => /tmp
            [opcache.file_cache] => 
            [opcache.file_cache_only] => 
            [opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks] => 1
            [opcache.file_update_protection] => 2
            [opcache.opt_debug_level] => 0
            [opcache.restrict_api] => 
            [opcache.huge_code_pages] => 
            [opcache.preload] => 
            [opcache.preload_user] => 
            [opcache.jit] => tracing
            [opcache.jit_buffer_size] => 268435456
            [opcache.jit_debug] => 0
            [opcache.jit_bisect_limit] => 0
            [opcache.jit_blacklist_root_trace] => 16
            [opcache.jit_blacklist_side_trace] => 8
            [opcache.jit_hot_func] => 127
            [opcache.jit_hot_loop] => 64
            [opcache.jit_hot_return] => 8
            [opcache.jit_hot_side_exit] => 8
            [opcache.jit_max_exit_counters] => 8192
            [opcache.jit_max_loop_unrolls] => 8
            [opcache.jit_max_polymorphic_calls] => 2
            [opcache.jit_max_recursive_calls] => 2
            [opcache.jit_max_recursive_returns] => 2
            [opcache.jit_max_root_traces] => 1024
            [opcache.jit_max_side_traces] => 128
            [opcache.jit_prof_threshold] => 0
        )

    [version] => Array
        (
            [version] => 8.0.14
            [opcache_product_name] => Zend OPcache
        )
```

code:

```
<?=print_r(opcache_get_status(FALSE), TRUE)?>
and
<?=print_r(opcache_get_configuration(), TRUE)?>
```

ini:

```
;configuration for php opcache module 
priority=10 
opcache.enable=1 
opcache.enable_cli=1 
opcache.jit=tracing 
opcache.jit_buffer_size=256M
```

you can look at [HERE](https://git.leoceramika.com/opcache/index.php)
what wrong guys, what to do to make it work

Comment: Can you provide the .ini file, the commandline you use it with and the code you used above to receive that output?

Comment: [edit] your question, don't put that into comments!

Comment: Do you have (had) by any chance xdebug enabled? XDebug and opcache.JIT are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I found it was because I had xDebug enabled - You need to disable it for JIT to function.

Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754934/1298155) to disable it.

If it isn't in your `php.ini` file, it will be in a xDebug `ini` file - search `phpinfo()` for "xdebug" and there should be a file it lists, edit that file.